# How to put question name in comment?

Tags: support

I've seen comments linking to other SE questions where the comment name is shown instead of just a meaningless hyperlink. How do I do that?

Comment: There's a "help" link to the right of any comment field. It has the answer, plus a link to [this handy page](http://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) that mentions a few other tricks most people aren't even aware exist.

Comment: @RegDwight I'd never seen that before—hidden in plain sight, I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a link with descriptive text like so:

> [descriptive text](http:\siteurl.org)

For example, I can give a [link to this very question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2587/how-to-put-question-name-in-comment) this way. It works in questions, answers, and comments.

A hint to finding how people do things is to do an edit of the original text (but then cancel of course). Most of the markup that works in questions/answers will work in comments/chat, too.

Comment: Ah! Normally I would have just gone into edit mode and seen the markup, but comments don't have that, and the link format in posts is multi-line. Thanks!

Comment: @zpletan: If you click the "help" link just below the "Add Comment" button, all the hints appear directly below the text box, including this formatting trick.